# Leer un JSON en javascript

Tags: javascript, json

No sé cómo leer un JSON en javascript, normalmente lo he hecho, pero esta vez me lee como un array desde la consola del inspector.

El JSON se genera de la siguiente manera:

```
JSON 1.
{persona:[{"ustelefono":"3544432","usidrol":0,"userid":1,"usapellidos":"Perez","useremail":"andrea@gmail.com","usnombres":"Andrea"}]}
//-------------
JSON 2
[{"ustelefono":"3544432","usidrol":0,"userid":0,"usapellidos":"Perez","useremail":"andrea@gmail.com","usnombres":"Andrea"}]
```

En la consola en el inspector del navegador me sale que es un array; no sé qué estoy haciendo mal o podría ser por los [] en la cadena.

```
$.post("usuario?accion=consultar", {usuario: idusuario}, function (rs) {

        var datos = JSON.parse(rs);

        console.log(datos.ustelefono);
        console.log(datos.usapellidos);

    });
```

Comment: eso no es un json valido...

Comment: @gbianchi de hecho los dos son validos, solo que ella no los encerro entre cadenas de texto, es como cuando imprimes con un echo desde `PHP` un json, la respuesta sera parecida a alguna de esas dos tal cual.

Comment: el segundo seria un json dentro de un array.. el primero seria un json con un solo valor, que es un array.. hay una parte que es un json valido, pero asi como estan, serian un json valido? @Riven...

Comment: digo, como para que el parse funcione... @Riven

Comment: El segundo es mas cercano a un json por los [] por eso js lo lee como un array por que pase una lista a convertir en json pero cuando retorna el json me lo retorna con los [] lo que hice en js para poder recibir bn el json fue esto, nose si es buena practica pero fue mi solucion y fue quitar el primer y ultimo caracter de la cadena que eran los [] y luego si hacer el json.parse y pues funciono


```
 var jsoncadena = rs.slice(1, -1);
        console.log(jsoncadena);
        var datos = JSON.parse(jsoncadena);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El primer código es inválido, porque *persona* debería estar entre comillas.

Suponiendo que cualquiera de los dos llegase como JSON válido, ambos incluyen los datos en un arreglo de un elemento y, dentro, la información del usuario y debes acceder con:

> Primer caso: `json1.persona[0].nombre_de_dato`
> Segundo caso: `json2[0].nombre_de_dato`

```js
let cadena1 = '{"persona":[{"ustelefono":"3544432","usidrol":0,"userid":1,"usapellidos":"Perez","useremail":"andrea@gmail.com","usnombres":"Andrea"}]}';

let cadena2 = '[{"ustelefono":"3544432","usidrol":0,"userid":0,"usapellidos":"Perez","useremail":"andrea@gmail.com","usnombres":"Andrea"}]';

let json1 = JSON.parse(cadena1);
let json2 = JSON.parse(cadena2);

// Acceder a ustelefono con el primer json
console.log(json1.persona[0].ustelefono);

// Acceder a ustelefono con el segundo json
console.log(json2[0].ustelefono);
```

Comment: Oye muchas gracias esta super como lo hiciste tu, pues yo lo hice fue quitando los caracteres [] y ya pero la tuya esta super tan bien me sirve muchas gracias triby

Answer (score 1):

Como ya han explicado arriba, el primer `JSON` que tienes tiene un formato invalido, puesto que un formato `JSON` se trata de una simple cadena de texto, cadena de texto la cual puede ser parseada a un **objeto de javascript**, un objeto de `javascript` es mas flexible en cuanto a sintaxis, puesto que por ejemplo un objeto javascript no requiere de comillas dobles en sus propiedades:

```js
const persona = {persona:[{"ustelefono":"3544432","usidrol":0,"userid":1,"usapellidos":"Perez","useremail":"andrea@gmail.com","usnombres":"Andrea"}]}

console.log(persona);
```

Eso que ves arriba se puede porque es un **objeto de javascript con formato JSON**, mas **NO** es directamente un `JSON`, hay ciertas particularidades extensas que lleva por detras hablar sobre el formato JSON, pero en resumen ese primer `JSON` que tienes para que sea valido deberia verse asi:

```
{
  "persona":
  [
    {
      "ustelefono":"3544432",
      "usidrol": 0,
      "userid": 1,
      "usapellidos": "Perez",
      "useremail": "andrea@gmail.com",
      "usnombres": "Andrea"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ese seria tu `JSON` corregido y formateado, como vemos cada propiedad debe ser encerrada entre comillas dobles, y además las comillas simples en un `JSON` estan prohibidas.

Por lo tanto, para verificarte de que el primer `JSON` es incorrecto debido a su formato vamos a usar `JSON.parse`, asi tal cual lo tenias en tu codigo original (pero encerrandolo entre comillas para poder ser legitimamente considerado como un `JSON`):

```js
const json = `{persona:[{"ustelefono":"3544432","usidrol":0,"userid":1,"usapellidos":"Perez","useremail":"andrea@gmail.com","usnombres":"Andrea"}]}`;

console.log(JSON.parse(json));      //ERROR
```

Sin embargo quiero clarificarte un poco mas, ya que aparentemente no sabias que un `objeto json` puede ser directamente un array que contiene dentro otros `objetos json`, y asi hasta el infinito en la recursividad.

por lo tanto, esto de aqui es valido:

```
{
  "prop1": "valor1",
  "prop2": [
     "subProp1": "subvalor1"
  ]
}
```

Y esto otro de aqui es igual de valido:

```
[
  {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": {
       "subProp1": "subvalor1",
       "subProp2": [0, 2, 4]
    }
  }
]
```

Como vemos el primer ejemplo usa llaves (`{}`) de inicio, mientras que el segundo usa corchetes (`[]`), pero ambos son validos, por lo tanto para acceder a las propiedades de un `json` (que cabe aclarar que el `json` es todo el cuerpo en si), deberas accederlas por sus **propiedades** si se trata de un objeto (`{}`), mientras que si se trata de un array deberas accederlas por indices numericos.

Aqui un ejemplo de cada uno muy sencillo:

**Objeto json**:

```js
const json = {
  name: "luis",
  amigos: ["julian", "andres", "luisa"]
}

console.log(json.name);
console.log(json.amigos[1]);
```

En este ejemplo accedemos al valor de la propiedad `name` del objeto y ademas tambien accedemos a la propiedad `amigos` del objeto, pero como amigos es un array podemos entonces usar indices numericos luego como hemos visto para obtener uno en especifico.

**Array**:

```js
const json = [
  {
    name: "juan",
    amigos: ["primer amigo", "segundo amigo", "tercer amigo"]
  },
  {
    name: "luis",
    amigos: ["primer amigo", "segundo amigo", "tercer amigo"],
    infoMejorAmigo: {
      direccion: "cra 33#8kC",
      nombre: "julian"
    }
  }
];

console.log(json[0].name);
console.log(json[1].infoMejorAmigo.direccion);
```

Como vemos, lo que hemos hecho en ese ejemplo es que de inicios hay un array, un array que contiene varios objetos, entonces lo que hacemos para acceder al deseado es que como se trata de un array deberas usar indices numericos partiendo del 0, por lo que el primer objeto seria `json[0]` el segundo `json[1]` y asi sucesivamente.

Dada esta informacion podras acceder a cualquier propiedad que quieras, como por ejemplo el valor de la propiedad `direccion` que solo existe dentro del segundo objeto.

Comment: @Riven muchas gracias enserio esta super tu informacion y muy clara gracias por tu colaboracion tendre en cuenta todas las soluciones que me brindaros pues las probe y sirven genial ya aprendi varias maneras con ustedes, gracias chicos

Comment: Lei la respuesta de `triby` mas detenidamente, es cierto el `json` no es valido, tanto tu como `triby`, como `gbianchi` tienen razon, pues al json le faltaban comillas en la palabra `persona` sin ellas al hacer `JSON.parse` habria un error, disculpen mi igorancia y por no haberlo notado, lo voy a corregir para no confundir al `OP`.